# Function name is used as SQL query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I've got a problem very similar to the ones found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583307/why-does-cakephp-use-this-method-name-in-a-mysql-query-rather-than-return-the-re) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382597/cakephp-executes-method-names-as-sql-queries), but these solutions aren't helping me fix my version of the problem. I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and I'm trying to call some model functions from within a view controller:

```
//Class setup
var $uses = array('StudentsTelephone', 'AddressesStudent');

//...

function someFunction(){
    $this->set('telephones', $this->StudentsTelephone->getActiveStudentTelepone($id));
    $this->set('addresses', $this->AddressesStudent->getActiveByStudentId($id));
}
```

This first of the model function calls (StudentsTelephone) works, but the second (AddressesStudent) fails. It attempts to use the function name as the SQL call resulting in:

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getActiveByStudentId' at line 1 [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

Using a little bit of debugging, I find out that the function is being looked for in the AppModel and AddressesStudent is never checked. Based on those other solutions it looks like it should be a typo in the name. However, everything appears to be correctly named. The above code is as stated, the model file is `addresses_student.php`, the class name is AddressesStudent and this was working fine before I updated Cake (just recently switched from 1.1 to 1.3). Any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem is not a naming error? Or maybe some other naming error that I'm missing? Thank you much!

EDIT: Also, here's the backtrace telling me that the model PHP file was never found:

```
DboSource::showQuery() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684
DboSource::execute() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 266
DboSource::fetchAll() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 410
DboSource::query() - CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 364
Model::call__() - CORE\cake\libs\model\model.php, line 502
Overloadable::__call() - CORE\cake\libs\overloadable_php5.php, line 50
AppModel::getActiveByStudentId() - [internal], line ??
StudentsController::edit() - APP\controllers\students_controller.php, line 277
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 83
```

Comment: can you paste your schema?

Comment: @mbarlocker: The schema for what now? The database for the addresses_student model? I could, but since the function call never even finds the model PHP file would that information be useful?

Comment: @mbarlocker: I just added the backtrace showing that Cake tries to find the function in the AppModel rather than AddressesStudent, which means the problem is in finding AddressesStudent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CakePHP uses the 'cached' auto-generated Model

For HABTM relations, CakePHP will automatically generate a 'generic' model for the JOIN-table (by creating an instance AppModel) **even if a Model exists for the join-table** (don't ask me why!)

*CakePHP stores this auto-generated model in its cache so that it can be reused in other locations.*

In your example, you try to use the `AddressesStudent` model. CakePHP will look for a model with that name, and finds a model with that name inside the *cache*. **This is, however the auto-generated model for the HABTM relation, not your actual model!**

### Tell CakePHP to use *your* model and *not* an auto-generated model

To prevent CakePHP from auto-generating a model for HABTM relations, add the `with` option to those relations; be sure to specify this at *both* sides of the relation (if you defined it at both sides, that is)

Inside the Student model;

```
$public hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Address' => array(
        // tell CakePHP to use the AddressesStudent model,
        // NOT and auto-generated model
        'with' => 'AddressesStudent',
    ),
);
```

And/or inside the Address model;

```
$public hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'with' => 'AddressesStudent',
    ),
);
```

By doing this, you're preventing that the cache contains auto-generated models.;

> with: Defines the name of the model for the join table. By default CakePHP will auto-create a model for you. Using the example above it would be called RecipesTag. By using this key you can override this default name. The join table model can be used just like any “regular” model to access the join table directly.

More information; [hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm)

Comment: I'm so sorry. This is already what I have in my code. I made a typo when writing out the question which I have just fixed in an edit now. Sorry again.

Comment: You do deserve a thumbs up for the work, but I won't give it to this answer as I still need to find the answer for my actual problem. So you can delete this answer, but I'll go to another of your answers to give it a plus.

Comment: @golmschenk first of all, are you using the same table as a HABTM relation in other locations? It may be that (as mentioned in my answer) that CakePHP is using the cached model. To explicitly use your own model, it may be worth a try to specify the `className` in the HABTM relation(s) to prevent CakePHP automatically creating a model; See [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Models.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm). Also, try to clear the cache-directories `app/tmp/cache/persistent` and `app/tmp/cache/models`

Comment: @golmschenk will remove my answer later on, first try if I can help you locate the problem :)

Comment: @golmschenk oops, just noticed I mentioned setting `className` inside the HABTM, for HABTM this should be the name of the 'other' model, **I *meant* to say** the `with` option; your should set this to the name of your Model (`AddressesStudent`) to force CakePHP to use **your** model, not an automatically generated one, and to prevent it caching the automatically generated model

Comment: Adding `'with' => 'AddressesStudent'` seemed to fix it. I'm getting a different SQL error now, but it does appear that the model is being found now. I'm still a little confused on why this fixes it and it won't run without it, but it works. Maybe it's just the cache and I should try clearing that first.

Comment: Well, CakePHP will auto-generate the 'join' model the first time it needs it, and store that generated model as `AddressesStudent`. Inside your controller, you're trying to use the `AddressesStudent` model; CakePHP looks for that model, and finds the **auto-generated** model inside the cache. It will therefore not look further for the *actual* model. By specifying the `with`, you force CakePHP to **not** auto-generate a model, but use the **actual** model you created. It *is* strange that CakePHP prefers auto-generated models over *actual* models.

Comment: That makes sense, but I just cleared the models and persistent cache and it still doesn't work without the 'with' option. I'm still curious to know why that isn't working without the 'with' but so long as that way works I'm happy. Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29335/discussion-between-thajeztah-and-golmschenk)

Comment: Sorry, kind of disappeared after that last comment.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a whole day, my solution to this problem was a typo in the models filename. I used `discounts.php` where it should have been `discount.php`.

I hope this helps someone!